# Reject: This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I have a problem that my code edits are rejected as addressing the **author**. In no way am I addressing the author? I am making the code work - it did not work before - and adding comments so that the **user** of code knows:

1. comments about what to do with the code in case more adjustments are needed by the user - there are other instructions of same kind already present in the code, so it is therefore even more expected to make all necessary instructions present.
2. comments about what or why the added code does what it does.

My previous (simpler) edit was also rejected, with a different reason: "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post" - not much better understandable reason in my mind though... 

This time I moved all talk into the code comments and added one more bugfix which I think is even more important.

What is wrong? Why did the reject reason change? Why did all reviewers who did reject a particular edit, somehow reject with the same reason even though that reason changed across edit tries?

I tried to add my thoughts as comments under the answer, as the reject suggests. The result looks pretty ridiculous I am afraid.

The edit in question is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7210334

Comment: Editing code is always dangerous....

Comment: Good ol' "lots of green/red, must reject"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, you are proposing a change to the answer (not its presentation), and give a good rationale for it.

That's not something you should just do to someone elses work:
Post a comment and let the OP incorporate or ignore it.
You might even want to post your own answer, if you think that's a crucial enough enhancement.

Comment: I'd agree with this if it wasn't so common for good suggestions to be ignored.

Comment: @Salgat: It *would* be nice if everyone always properly respected my correct opinion.

Comment: That's the beauty of moderation, bad suggestions can be rejected.

Comment: @Salgat You are assuming that all the reviewers are vetted subject experts, and have the time to research things themselves if it isn't obvious. Unfortunately, doing it that way simply doesn't work, we would need a few orders of magnitude more experts. Also, the obvious is sometimes simpy wrong.

Comment: And to repeat, the beauty of it is that it can be edited again to correct the rare times it slips through the cracks with an explanation for why their edit was wrong. Considering Wikipedia among other sites handle this with incredible success, I'm for it since in most cases it will improve the answer.

Comment: This just makes the site overflow with superfluous answers. Some answers are simply outdated. Anyways.. I'm glad there are still enough people on stackoverflow trying to make the site the most helpful possible and that these rejects are only about 10% from my experience. **Because edits should NOT just be display changes BUT also content!**

Answer (score 29):

Edits exist to improve the post author's presentation of *their own content*.  They are not there for you to introduce your own content into the post, or to change what you think are errors in the code.

If it's clear that the author intended to write one thing, and in fact wrote another, you could fix that (for example, a typo on a variable name).  But if it's not clear that the author intended to write what you're changing the answer to, then the edit is not appropriate.

If you feel that an answer is wrong, or has a mistake, you can comment on that answer with the problem (as you have since done).  If you feel that the problem is significant enough, you can downvote the post.  If you feel that the additional information you're providing warrants it (I don't think it does in this case, but for completeness' sake) you could add a new answer for your own content (be sure to appropriately cite any material that is not your own when doing this).

Comment: I think the author intended exactly one thing but it had mistakes in it. I am not adding new functionality or changing it from the intended (and single) one. I never could imagine that the current SO policy is to add an other similar answer to compete with existing idea with buggy implementation. But now I know and keep that in mind, so thank you! First I try to comment, then post fixed answer of my own. 

I would like to propose an optional form of edits where edits go directly into the answer/code, not into comments, but instead of random people doing review, the author does the reviews.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. I have done one code edit before. Should it actually have been rejected too? The edit is here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3561546/revisions The reason for edit was same - the existing code was unusable since it did not perform its single purpose on certain cases.

Comment: @RolandPihlakas Your previous edit should have been rejected yes.  If you want to propose a change that the post author can either apply or not apply, then *post a comment*.  That accomplishes that goal.

Comment: I am still somewhat confused. According to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code my edits are explicitly neither disallowed nor encouraged: The only clauses I think were applicable are these: "Editing Code in Answers: Do: Test your edited code to make sure it works; Don't: Make the code do something different than what the answer says it does". In my mind the latter actually implicitly tells DO make the code do something the answer says it does. AND if the code currently does not do what the answer says it does, then it needs to be edited....

Comment: @RolandPihlakas To quote from the quesiton you linked; edits should be used: "To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)".  If the author of the post *intended* the code to be what it is, that's how you should leave it.  If you think it's wrong, comment or post another answer.  If the author clearly intended the code to be something else, then editing is appropriate.

Comment: Yes I think the authors clearly intended the code to be something else in both cases. I think posting code fixes in comments is rather limited form of communication since the space is limited and formatting is also limited. And posting alternate answers causes clutter. Should I open a new question proposing a form of edits which are directed so that the authors will be able to review them instead of hurried people unfamiliar with the problem?

Comment: You *can*.  I highly doubt that it'd be implemented, but don't let that stop you from asking.

Comment: I never knew until now that edits were not supposed to improve the correctness of answer, but only the presentation. I think rejection message is very misleading. It would be a lot more clear if it just said, "Edits are only for improving presentation and not correcting errors." or had a link to an FAQ.

Comment: How about this rejection? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9426999 All I am doing is to reinstate the original question which is far better than the current one.

Comment: @Iyas Had your revision comment indicated that you were adding information removed by other editors, rather than just adding your own example, then it would have actually been appropriate to accept it, but given that you didn't, rejecting it is entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

Editing exist so users can improve posts. If your edit is an **unambiguous improvement**, meaning that you are only changing a question or answer in ways that are 100% positive, and do not make dramatic alterations, go ahead and make the edit. If it's ambiguous, meaning your edit may or may not be what the author intended, or your changes are 90% positive but 10% negative/unsure, then make a comment or create your own answer.

Be warned, SO reviewers are capricious, inconsistent, and frequently hostile to people simply trying to make improvements, so your 100% positive edits may be rejected anyway. The stock rejection messages are often incomprehensible and unrelated to the content of your edit.

SO only values answering questions, not asking questions, editing questions, or editing answers. Until you have 2000 rep, you are considered a nuisance, not a contributor if you attempt to make edits.

Comment: Your first paragraph is pretty good, maybe a bit off. Your second paragraph rather exaggerates the extent of the problem, and your third is pretty thoroughly wrong.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I have been told in no uncertain terms that making minor edits is **harmful** to SO. My second paragraph is an accurate reflection of my, and others' experiences as new users, and my third paragraph is a reflection of what actual high-rep users routinely write on Meta.SO. It is deliberately not phrased in a diplomatic way, because I see no point in sugar-coating things. New users should know how bad things are so they aren't blindsided when they have edits rejected for incomprehensible reasons, get downvoted for breaking rules that have not been properly explained, etc.

Comment: I've been a prolific suggester (I almost stopped getting rep from it), a prolific edit reviewer (almost 4k reviews), and highly active on MSO (whose is that ugly black-and-white photo near the bottom of the [first page of active users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users)? is that mine?) — and I have my share of complaints about bad reviewers. That paragraph just doesn't square with what I've seen anywhere on SO or SE. I'm not saying it hasn't been your experience. But I do think it's reasonable to urge caution before overgeneralizing like this.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, people have different experiences with edit suggestions. It's not a very transparent process: other factors than just the merit of a given suggestion play a role, such as a user's approval/rejection ratio. Maybe your positive track record put you above the threshold for having a good experience with edit suggestions. The characterization is very accurate to my experience, and I think the underlying problems are vague guidelines, liberal interpretations of same, and a lack of transparency.